# How can I use spatially filtered PostGIS layers in QGIS without losing the ability to edit them in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, editing, spatial-query, data-management

I have some vector layers for a whole country stored in a PostGIS database. I want to use that data in different QGIS projects that stand for different regions of the country. In the regional QGIS projects I want to spatially filter the vector-layers to the specific regions.

In other words: different projects should use different filters but the same data source.

I used a spatial SQL Query in QGIS, but the problem is I can't edit that filtered layer anymore (blue dots), the edit button is greyed out.

This is the SQL query I used:

```
select d.*
from db_betriebsstellen as d
join bundeslaender as b
on ST_WITHIN(d.geom, b.geom) where b.name = ‘Bayern’
```

[image]

I remember using a spatial filter toolbar in Geomedia in the past. The specific spatial filter preference was saved in the Geoworkspace (*.gws) which is in Geomedia the same thing like the Project in QGIS (*.qgz).

[image]

Now I would like to have a similar functionality in QGIS / PostGIS. Any ideas on how to achieve that? Maybe a plugin?

Comment: The JOIN might be the issue here. For spatial filtering you can use the layer's Filter feature with PostGIS functions.

Comment: @bugmenot123 thanks, but then I can't do a filter which is using an object of another table. I want to use a polygon-object of another layer (regions) in order to filter the objects in the given layer e.g. "betriebsstellen".

Comment: Wild guess but try: `ST_WITHIN(geom, (SELECT geom FROM bundeslaender WHERE name = 'Bayern')` as filter condition, does that work?

Comment: No that doesn't work. I get this error message: Ein Fehler trat beim Ausführen der Abfrage auf.
Der Datenanbieter meldete:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LIMIT"
LINE 1: ...ELECT geom FROM bundeslaender WHERE name = 'Bayern') LIMIT 0

Comment: Sorry, missed a closing `)`. Try `ST_WITHIN(geom, (SELECT geom FROM bundeslaender WHERE name = 'Bayern'))`.

Comment: Wow, that works perfect !!!

Comment: Awesome, even for editing? I'll write it as an answer then.

Comment: Yes, it works for editing !! After your answer I can also share my screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filter on the plain layer instead (rightclick the layer in the layer tree, "Filter"). For PostGIS layers you can use full SQL in there.

This is a filter query string that should resemble your query and you will be able to edit the filtered layer:

```
ST_WITHIN(geom, (SELECT geom FROM bundeslaender WHERE name = 'Bayern'))
```

If you would like a nice GUI for this, check out the https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spatial_filter/ plugin.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS won't let you edit query result sets - these are virtual tables, and would require complex logic implemented to guarantee a link to the respective physical sources of the query.

Instead, you want to **use *Views***: while QGIS doesn't support that behavior above by itself, PostgreSQL does to some extend - if a *View* is *simple* enough (see [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) under "*Updatable Views*") PostgreSQL let's you run CRUD operations on them; in your case, instead of a `JOIN` that renders the *View* **not** update-able, you can use a simple `EXISTS` filter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW db_betriebsstellen__bayern AS
  SELECT
    d.*
  FROM
    db_betriebsstellen AS d
  WHERE
    EXISTS (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        bundeslaender AS b
      WHERE
        ST_Intersects(d.geom, b.geom)
        AND
        b.name = 'Bayern'
    )
;
```

---

As long as your requirements are expressible with a single table as source (or another *update-able View*) and corresponding `WHERE` filter predicates, you can use the above approach. If you have more complex needs, you can make a *View* update-able using `INSTEAD OF` triggers - a little more complex to set up, but yielding ultimate control over specific data extraction and its CRUD permissions and abilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reality is like this: we have 50 project regions (and growing) and 20 layers for Germany. That would result in 1000 views, I guess it's a bit overwhelming to handle...

Comment: @EnzoBaldini given your setup it looks to me like you will have to manage 1000 things one way or another - managing *Views* can be automated with functions and triggers, and you can manage them centralized in your DB.